# convert list<object> into key value pair

Tags: java, list, object, dictionary

When I execute this query I get the result in list

```
List<Object> movlist=movquery.list();
```

the result is like

```
[["VOD1000","sdf","Malayalam"],["VOD1002","sdf","English"],["VOD1004","sdf","Hindi"]]
```

But I need to get the result like

```
[{"channelId":"VOD1000","channelName":"sdf","channelLanguage":"Malayalam",},
{"channelId":"VOD1000","channelName":"sdf","channelLanguage":"Malayalam",},
{"channelId":"VOD1000","channelName":"sdf","channelLanguage":"Malayalam",}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: basically you want to place Map inside List?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do.  What is the runtime type of the objects in movquery.list()?  When you say "the result is like", how did you get that string?  By calling movlist.toString()?

Comment: I think movlist should be a model class rather than 'Object'

Comment: @AkashRajbanshino.. it is a object list. not a model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is a JSON String output, I'd suggest the quick and dirty solution below:

```
List<Object> movlist=movquery.list();
String s = "[";
for(Object o:movlist){
   Object[] array = (Object[]) o;
   s += "{\"channelId\":\""+array[0]+"\",\"channelName\":\""+array[1]+"\",\"channelLanguage\":\""+array[2]+"\",},";
}
s += "]";
```

Comment: From The Clean Coder by Robert C. Martin: Professionals realize that “quick and dirty” is an oxymoron. Dirty always means slow...

Comment: You better use a `StringBuilder` instead of multiple `+=`.